# Align Grid JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I need an help to align this table. I don't know work with design. How I can align and adapt size to each column, and the table in full size in my window?

I want all auto align. Width and Height (Full size).
My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        source =
        {
            datatype: "xml",
            datafields: [
                { name: 'User', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'AccessGroup', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'FolderAccess', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'RequestDate', type: 'Date' },
                { name: 'SituationDesc', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'Approver', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'ApprovalDate', type: 'Date' },
                { name: 'BusinessJustification', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'AllBusinessJustification', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'UserRequestor', type: 'string' }
            ],
            async: false,
            record: 'Table',
            url: 'Tickets.aspx/GetTickets',
        };

        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
        );
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
            width: 3000,
            source: dataAdapter,
            theme: 'classic',
            autoheight: true,
            columns: [
              { text: 'User', datafield: 'User', widht: 'auto' },
              { text: 'Access Group', datafield: 'AccessGroup', widht: 'auto' },
              { text: 'Folder Access', datafield: 'FolderAccess', widht: 'auto' },
              { text: 'Request Date', datafield: 'RequestDate', widht: 'auto' },
              { text: 'Situation', datafield: 'SituationDesc', widht: 'auto' },
              { text: 'Approver', datafield: 'Approver', widht: 'auto' },
              { text: 'Approval Date', datafield: 'ApprovalDate', widht: 'auto' },
              { text: 'Business Justification', datafield: 'BusinessJustification', widht: 'auto' },
              { text: 'All Business Justifications', datafield: 'AllBusinessJustification', widht: 'auto' },
              { text: 'User Requestor', datafield: 'UserRequestor', widht: 'auto' },

            ]
        });
    });

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div align="center" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <img src="image/NdriveBanner.png" align="center" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="jqxgrid">
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div align="center" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/image/home_back_48.png"
            NavigateUrl="~/home.aspx">homepage</asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code which shows how to set the Grid's size in percentages so it will be auto-resized.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title id='Description'>In this sample, the Grid's size is set in percentages. When you resize the browser's window, the Grid's Width and Height will be automatically adjusted. The "width" and "height" properties of jqxGrid in this sample are set to "50%"</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.filter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.sort.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxpanel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcalendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdatetimeinput.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/globalization/globalize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/gettheme.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="generatedata.js"></script>
    <style>
        body, html {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var theme = getDemoTheme();

            var data = generatedata(500);
            var source =
            {
                localdata: data,
                datafields:
                [
                    { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'productname', type: 'string' },
                    { name: 'available', type: 'bool' },
                    { name: 'date', type: 'date'},
                    { name: 'quantity', type: 'number' }
                ],
                datatype: "array"
            };

            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

            $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
            {
                width: '50%',
                height: '50%',
                source: dataAdapter,
                showfilterrow: true,
                filterable: true,
                theme: theme,
                selectionmode: 'multiplecellsextended',
                columns: [
                  { text: 'Name', columntype: 'textbox',  datafield: 'name', width: '20%' },
                  {
                      text: 'Product', datafield: 'productname', width: '35%'
                  },
                  { text: 'Ship Date', datafield: 'date', filtertype: 'date', width: '30%', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'd' },
                  { text: 'Qty.', datafield: 'quantity', width: '15%',  cellsalign: 'right' }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
    <div id="jqxgrid">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jqgrid is providing the align property to each columns, to align header you need to change in the jqgrid css to the respective call for the headers.

for the align in columns you can add like this

```
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
            width: 3000,
            source: dataAdapter,
            theme: 'classic',
            autoheight: true,
            columns: [
              { text: 'User', datafield: 'User', widht: 'auto',align="center" },
              { text: 'Access Group', datafield: 'AccessGroup', widht: 'auto',align="center" },
              { text: 'Folder Access', datafield: 'FolderAccess', widht: 'auto',align="center" },
              { text: 'Request Date', datafield: 'RequestDate', widht: 'auto',align="center" },
              { text: 'Situation', datafield: 'SituationDesc', widht: 'auto',align="center" },
              { text: 'Approver', datafield: 'Approver', widht: 'auto' ,align="center"},
              { text: 'Approval Date', datafield: 'ApprovalDate', widht: 'auto',align="center" },
              { text: 'Business Justification', datafield: 'BusinessJustification', widht: 'auto',align="center" },
              { text: 'All Business Justifications', datafield: 'AllBusinessJustification', widht: 'auto',align="center" },
              { text: 'User Requestor', datafield: 'UserRequestor', widht: 'auto' ,align="center"},

            ]
        });
```